# JS to rotate a variable stack of images in a variable set of elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, rest, sharepoint

OK so I am relatively new to JS and the REST API (so please be gentle)

I am using REST to pull from a sharepoint list.  This populates a slider with multiple divs that include both an image and text. I would like to make the image a slider itself (without controls) that will swap out images for the unique slider item.

The code is written so a user can populate multiple images on a single slider element and the images will stack on top of each other and change every few moments from one image to another. I am having trouble coming up with a function that will treat each slider div uniquely given an unknown number of images and/or slider elements.  I attempted to put walls to say a maximum of 10 sliders elements will exist, but any number of images could be populated for any one slider element.

My REST code works as it should and populates the images in a stack but now i need to assign visibility or order to the images.  Each list item can have anywhere from 0-X images.

Unfortunately I dont really have any code per say that would provide value here... the bounds of this is purely 'X' number of elements with 'N' number of images each.  I want each element x1, x2, x3... xx to swap images n1, n2, n3...nn every 2-3 seconds.

Here is the resulting HTML for the element. I created a unique id for each element -- this one is element 8 in the sharepoint list (pic8).  I then assign a dummyclass for the all images *dummyclass* I also append a unique ID  for each image (2pic0 2pic1 2pic2).  I also tried assigning data attributes -- data-index says the pic is the 1st 2nd or 3rd pic of the set and data-max is the max value of data-index -- this was meant to identify that there are 3 total (0, 1, 2) images so the data-max was set as 2 -- hopefully that makese sense.... I am honestly pulling at staws:

```
<div class="spotlight">
    <div class="img_spotlight" id="pic8">
        <img class="dummyClass" id="2pic0" data-index="0" data-max="2" src="image1.jpg">
        <img class="dummyClass" id="2pic1" data-index="1" data-max="2" src="image2.jpg">
        <img class="dummyClass" id="2pic2" data-index="2" data-max="2" src="image3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="spotlight_content">
        <div class="spotlight_title"><h3>TITLE</h3></div>
        <div class="spotlight_body"><p>WORDS HERE</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My intuition is to use a function that will pull all children from each div and swap visibility or z-index.  This function would of course need to exist outside of the ajax query which generates the image stack.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a bit of research i found an answer via the cycle() jquery plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/download/

This effectively takes the children and fades them in regardless of the number of elements. Hopefully this helps someone else in a similar position